# Calendar or Date to Cron Expression

Tags: java, date, calendar, cron, cronexpression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a java class for constructing a cron expression using a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520705/is-there-a-java-class-for-constructing-a-cron-expression-using-a-date)

Is there a better way to convert Calendar or Date to cron expression than using string concating?
Like;

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();    
String cronExpression = now.get(Calendar.SECOND) + " " + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + " " + now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " ? " + now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: @rekire: First hit on Google: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström ah that stuff. I did not know that name